# cloth simulation going through collision mesh.?

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]

so my cloth simulation going through the mesh someone help me with this

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zlCqP_Yxd8QKNJGwxqQIDLVzZiu9NSv_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Nihal, could you pls add a blend file WITH your cloth modifier + settings so we can check your settings? thx and another hint: always(!) apply scale and rotation before starting a physics simulation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop surface of cloth plane from intersecting my cylinder?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264932/how-to-stop-surface-of-cloth-plane-from-intersecting-my-cylinder)

Comment: @Chris https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zlCqP_Yxd8QKNJGwxqQIDLVzZiu9NSv_/view?usp=sharing . this is my blend file , i already applied the scale.

Comment: Hello, no cloth simulation has been assigned to the plane in the file you've shared, could you please share your file again, with the cloth simulation, and only the plane + car?

Comment: sorry for the late response, having some network issue in my area 
 heres another blend file @moonboots      https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-OCAuPnodx8zit8TQNmK7GicOtt8fRJu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: My computer is a bit too slow for this simulation, you probably need to play with these parameters: Quality Steps, Collisions Quality and Object Collisions Distance

Comment: Uncheck *Single Sided* in the *Collision* options.

Answer (score 0):

this is "normal". Try increasing quality of collision and cloth. And yes, this makes the simulation slower - but more accurate. If this doesn't help, pls provide blend file.

Comment: didn't work i tried it with '20' quality for both

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zlCqP_Yxd8QKNJGwxqQIDLVzZiu9NSv_/view?usp=sharing
 here's the blend file